# Neural network training in Azure and Weka

Tags: azure, weka

I'm using some data-sets (.arff files) to train neural networks in Weka and Azure. For every data-set , I get an overall accuracy difference between WEKA/Azure up to 5%. Obviously, I use the same training parameters, like number of iterations, learning rate, momentum, etc. Is this difference justified?

Comment: Unless you're using exactly the same algorithm, with the same seed for any randomisation involved, then probably yes, but if you want a better answer than that you'll have to give more information on what you're doing and what the output is. Do you get the same accuracy if you train the same network twice with the same data?

Comment: Yes. Same accurasy with WEKA tries, same with all Azure tries. It's WEKA vs Azure that has some difference.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if your input data files are similar, still contain slightly different data values, then classification results are unlikely to be exactly the same between runs, and 5% variation is not unheard of.

Perform some experiments with a *single* dataset and only vary the "seed" attribute (maybe try 5 differnt integers), that will tell you how much randomness is involved in running your algorithm, MultilayerPerceptron I suppose.

(Seriously, what kind of answer do you expect here?)

Comment: As I wrote on the comment above, "Same accurasy with WEKA tries, same with all Azure tries. It's WEKA vs Azure that has some difference. " I have the training accuracy almost the same in each program, but it's between the programs that there is a small difference, up to 5%. An answer I would like is if this difference in outputs between these two programs has to do with the programs themselves, or Azure has some extra tweaks more than Weka in Neural Network training. I'm new to Azure, that's why I'm asking

Comment: Generally you provide too little information; the only person who can answer this is someone who has performed similar experiments on both platforms you've used, with similar, complex, algorithms and similar data. I'd say don't use Weka's MultilayerPerceptron because this is more a teaching tool and the Weka developer Prof. Witten is (was?) a skeptic of Neural Networks.